# How to Insert Popup box shortcode in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I create a Tinymce Popup box for inserting shortcode on content area in wordpress. When I click shortcode button then popup box open successfully with input field. But when I click popup box insert button then noting happen. I search on google and try so hard but I can't find out the problem. Please, anyone can help me. In the following is my popbox code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Insert Button</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" src="../../wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/wp_theme/dialog.css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/friendly_buttons_tinymce.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var ButtonDialog = {
    local_ed : 'ed',
    init : function(ed) {
        ButtonDialog.local_ed = ed;
        tinyMCEPopup.resizeToInnerSize();
    },
    insert : function insertButton(ed) {

        // Try and remove existing style / blockquote
        tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceRemoveNode', false, null);

        // set up variables to contain our input values
        var url = jQuery('#button-dialog input#button-url').val();
        var text = jQuery('#button-dialog input#button-text').val();
        var size = jQuery('#button-dialog select#button-size').val();
        var color = jQuery('#button-dialog select#button-color').val();      
        var style = jQuery('#button-dialog select#button-style').val();      
        var align = jQuery('#button-dialog select#button-align').val();      

        var output = '';

        // setup the output of our shortcode
        output = '[button ';
            output += 'size=' + size + ' ';
            output += 'style=' + style + ' ';
            output += 'color=' + color + ' ';
            output += 'align=' + align;

            // only insert if the url field is not blank
            if(url)
                output += ' url=' + url;
        // check to see if the TEXT field is blank
        if(text) {  
            output += ']'+ text + '[/button]';
        }
        // if it is blank, use the selected text, if present
        else {
            output += ']'+ButtonDialog.local_ed.selection.getContent() + '[/button]';
        }
        tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, output);

        // Return
        tinyMCEPopup.close();
    }
};
tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ButtonDialog.init, ButtonDialog);

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="button-dialog">
        <form action="/" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div>
                <label for="button-url">Button URL</label>
                <input type="text" name="button-url" value="" id="button-url" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="button-text">Button Text</label>
                <input type="text" name="button-text" value="" id="button-text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="button-size">Size</label>
                <select name="button-size" id="button-size" size="1">
                    <option value="small">Small</option>
                    <option value="medium" selected="selected">Medium</option>
                    <option value="large">Large</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="button-style">Style</label>
                <select name="button-style" id="button-style" size="1">
                    <option value="less_round">Less Round</option>
                    <option value="round" selected="selected">Round</option>
                    <option value="square">Square</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="button-color">Color</label>
                <select name="button-color" id="button-color" size="1">
                    <option value="gray" selected="selected">Gray</option>
                    <option value="blue"=>Blue</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="button-align">Alignment</label>
                <select name="button-align" id="button-align" size="1">
                    <option value="gray" selected="selected">None</option>
                    <option value="left"=>Left</option>
                    <option value="right">Right</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>   
                <a href="javascript:ButtonDialog.insert(ButtonDialog.local_ed)" id="insert" style="display: block; line-height: 24px;">Insert</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: were there any errors in the console?